# "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found" when importing installed module

Tags: python, installation, scipy, nltk, gensim

I'm using Window 10.1 and Python 3.4. I installed the nltk, numpy, scipy and gensim modules using wheel files (URL: [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)).

Here's a screenshot of the installed modules:

[image: Screenshot of installed modules]

When I'm running this statement:

```
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
```

I'm getting this Import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\sample.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gensim\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, matutils, interfaces, corpora, models, similarities, summarization
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gensim\matutils.py", line 21, in <module>
    import scipy.linalg
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .blas import get_blas_funcs
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 155, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you paste the error message instead of an screenshot, please?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9 to see how to setup NLTK on windows.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `pip` to install NLTK as suggested on http://www.nltk.org/install.html or try `conda` https://anaconda.org/anaconda/nltk. That should automatically install the dependencies for NLTK.

Please see https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9 for detailed installation guide for NLTK on Windows.